# How can I run a 'for' loop in SQL to get a set of results without casting a function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `users` in my DB, and I need to get the number of users in that table for a given date, for the last 90 days - this is to track the rate at which new users get registered in the system.

At that, I need to get the size of the table for each day, regardless of whether anybody registered or not on that particular day.

For this I am trying to use a `FOR` loop with `DO` statement - it so happens that **I'm working in read-only environment** and cannot even declare functions. Sadly, I can't get it to work. Either I'm doing something wrong, or it is impossible under such restrictions. Here's my code:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 0..90 LOOP
        RETURN QUERY (
            SELECT i "count", (current_date - i) "date", COUNT(u.id) "users"
            FROM users u
            WHERE date_trunc('day', u.created::timestamptz at time zone 'pst') <= (current_date - i)
            GROUP BY (current_date - i);)
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$do$;
```

I really want this to return:

```
count | date       | users
====================
1     | 13.04.2021 | 49855
2     | 12.04.2021 | 49812
3     | 11.04.2021 | 48993
....
90    | 14.01.2021 | 47522
```

but I only get

```
ERROR: cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function Position: 165
```

or something similar for `RETURN NEXT` if I try that one.

What can I do to achieve the desired result (besides better learn SQL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for this.

You can generate a list of 90 days using [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) and then join this to the users table

```
select g.dt::date as "date"
       count(*) as "users"
from generate_series(current_date - 90, current_date, interval '1 day') as g(dt)
  left join users u on u.created_at::date = g.dt::date
group by g.dt::date
order by g.dt::date desc;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, with a little adjustment: instead of `left join users u on u.created_at::date = g.dt::date` it should be `left join users u on u.created_at::date <= g.dt::date`